# Word for "Increasing Attention"?

Tags: names

I'm looking for a name for our project.
The project is aimed to resolve a low recall issue in our search system.
Basically, it tries to improve the attention of many items in the search index so that all of those matched fields could be returned in the search results.

Requirement: this name needs to be a single word, e.g. some famous people's name, etc.

I did a lot of research, and found `gasconade` might be a good name, but it's actually meaning to extravagent boasting, not exactly what I intended to mean.

Any ideas please?

More specs about this project:
Imagine you type `stack` in Google, only 5 results showed up in your first page, you're disappointed, right?
This project aims at fixing this issue, instead of returning 5, we'll return possibly 50 pages of result (each page with 30 results).
This is the purpose of this project.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are there other names used in the project  to describe different functions and roles?  This might help narrow and focus on a suitable choice.  Also, are you only looking for a word based on the name of a famous person's name or character?

Comment: How about _focus_?

Comment: Yes, that would be the most ideal. But I'm also open to other possibilities, but one word is mandatory. I added more details about the project in the original post. Thanks @Palizsche

Comment: That doesn't apply to this project very well. Not relevant enough. Thanks! @Xanne

Comment: *Crawler* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

Comment: Okay, how about "stentor".  This is a person with a powerful voice, but is based on the mythological character, Stentor, who as a herald, called the Greek troops to fight.

Comment: I suppose Highlight or Spotlight is too generic,  Entertainment terms like "Top Billing" or "Headligner" come to mind.. or perhaps "Marquee" (although marquee typically would have the top few names.. not 30) .

Comment: What about 'attract'?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to focus on the meaning of the desired word? A sample everyday sentence using the word (not as the name of your product, just as a word) with a ___ where the word should be would be ideal. This will help us get a better handle on what you want, and will also help avoid closure of your question. (Note that help with [naming is off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site, while [single-word-requests are on-topic but do require a sample sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests).)

Comment: *Divining, divining rod, dowsing, brining* or *brinning* (from Sergey Brin). // "Attention" seems to be the wrong word.

Answer (score 0):

'**Increasing Attention**' makes me think of *sharpening*, and I'd chose the word

> **hone**:
> *to make more acute or effective; improve; perfect:*

however, it seems that rather than honing (refining) the results, your software is searching in a larger number of locations, to provide a wider field of results. This makes me think of

> **tentacles:** noun
> *1.
> any of a variety of long, slender, flexible growths, as about the head or mouth of some invertebrate animals, used variously for grasping, feeling, moving, etc.
> 2.  Botany
> any of various sensitive hairs on the leaves of some plants, as those used in capturing insects*

but also of many-eyed creatures (list from Wikipedia entry on the same):

> **Amun** in Egyptian mythology (in some depictions).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkmj4.jpg) **Argus Panoptes** in
> Greek mythology. **Azrael** in Islam. **Bes** in Egyptian mythology (in some
> depictions).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkmj4.jpg) **Ophanim** in Christianity. **Lord Shiva** in Hinduism.
> **Osiris** in Egyptian mythology (in some depictions).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkmj4.jpg) **Seraphim** in
> Christianity.

A mixture of the two above could be

> **Medusa**

[image: In English]

(Medusa in Greek mythology)

[image: In Spanish]

(Medusa in modern Spanish)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the product, it sounds like what you want is a word that describes finding things that ordinarily go unseen.  If that's the case, I would suggest the word ***[dilate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilate)***.

> to enlarge or expand in bulk or extent :  distend, widen.
>
> - *dilate our cultural knowledge*

The word packs a double meaning that could be perfect for your product.  It often refers to a widening of the eyes, specifically the pupils, to allow in more light so that things can be seen which would ordinarily be difficult to see in dim lighting.

> *Her pupils **dilated** in amazement*
>
> *As her pupils **dilated**, she could see the figure.*

But it can also simply refer to enlarging or widening scope or extent, as the definition states, so it seems to fit with your product in both a figurative and a literal way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas. But I'm more looking for a noun, or a popular figure that could represent the meaning of `dilate`. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Sieve.
If you're worried about recall then you can get a finer mesh, but your precision will suffer.
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sieve

Comment: You need to explain your answer to make it acceptable to ELU--otherwise it risks getting deleted.  Also documentation is appreciated.

Comment: Is that better?